# Hashing data from a Bio struct in linux

Tags: c, linux, encryption, io

My goal is to read the data stored in a bio (assuming that it is for a write operation) and compute its md5 fingerprint. The data could be anything. I made several attempts. Here is my latest attempt:

```
void fingerprint(struct bio * bio, unsigned char * result)
{
char * place;
char * cpy;
int total;
struct buffer_head * bh;
struct scatterlist sg;
struct hash_desc desc = {
    .tfm = crypto_alloc_hash("md5", 0, CRYPTO_ALG_ASYNC),
    .flags = CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_SLEEP
};
total = 0;

cpy = kmalloc(sizeof(char) * bio->bi_io_vec[i].bv_len, GFP_KERNEL);
bh = (struct buffer_head *)bio->bi_io_vec[i].bv_page->private;
    place = bh->b_data + bio->bi_io_vec[i].bv_offset;

DPRINTK("%u", bio->bi_io_vec[i].bv_offset);
DPRINTK("%u", place);

memcpy(cpy, place, bio->bi_io_vec[i].bv_len);
DPRINTK("%x", place);
DPRINTK("%x", cpy);

sg_init_one(&sg, (u8 *)cpy, bio->bi_io_vec[i].bv_len);
crypto_hash_init(&desc);
crypto_hash_update(&desc, &sg, bio->bi_io_vec[i].bv_len);
total += bio->bi_io_vec[i].bv_len;
DPRINTK("%u", bio->bi_vcnt);
DPRINTK("%u", total);

crypto_hash_final(&desc, result);
kfree(cpy);
}
```

The results of the hash are very similar if not exactly the same and they are always even numbers. I print out the results as long long's and in hex. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test your code.  Cut down your code to the MD5 minimum, and try a few test vectors.

"" -> d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" -> 9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6

"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." -> e4d909c290d0fb1ca068ffaddf22cbd0

(Note the extra full stop in the third example.)

Once you are sure MD5 is working correctly, then gradually reintroduce the other parts of your code and recheck regularly.

Comment: So I can see pieces of these results in my print outs, but some of the characters are jumbled. In what format should I print the output?

Comment: The test vectors I gave were in hex.